# If value is true update some columns, if not update anothers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i will try to explain my "issue"

i have two tables

```
Table1
id      parent_id     name                  active
2008    10          name0                      Y
200801  2008        child of name0             Y
200802  2008        child of name0             Y
201102  10434344    child of name0             Y

Table2
old_id  new_id     name                active     id_father_new
2008    10         name0                  N           0
200801  202101    child of name0          N          2021
200802  202102    child of name0          N          2021
2011    10        new name0               Y           0
201101  201101    child of new name0      Y          2011
201102  10434344  child of name0          Y          2011
201102  201103  child of new name0        Y          2011
```

How u can see, the first table have some id, id_parent and active field.
The other one have the same columns and new information and new records to add in table1.

All new records in table2 was inserted in table1 with left join and now i need to do an update in table1 with the information in table2 but only if **active** field in table2 is `Y` updated  id, id_parent and active field, if active field is N in table2 just update active field in table1

So, table1 should be like this:

```
Table1
    id        parent_id     name             active
    2008         10         name0                 N
    200801      2008        child of name0        N
    200802      2008        child of name0        N
    201102      2011        child of name0        Y
    10434344    2011        child of name0        Y
    2011        10          new name0             Y           
    201101      2011        child of new name0    Y
    201103      2011        child of new name0    Y
```

in the first three records only change active field to N because in table2 they were active = N

if i do this:

```
update u
        set u.id = s.new_id,
            u.parent_id = s.new_father_id,
            u.active = s.active
        from table1 u
        inner join table2 s on u.new_id = s.old_id
        where s.active like 'Y'
```

obviously only update rows with active = Y, and three first columns they remain with their same values, so its necessary make another update for field active:

```
update u
        set u.active = s.active
        from table1 u
        inner join table2 s on u.new_id = s.old_id
```

**The biggest question is,** ¿its possible to do this only with one update?, maybe with cursor ? CASE statement in set ? or just two updates its acceptable in good practices of sql

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can't you use a case-statement within your first update and leave away the where? Where is the problem? You proposed this already.

Comment: even though your OP is about the update but realistically there is an issue with your design.. hierarchical structure only needs 2 tables (well in this case)... one for names master and one for relationships...  then apply CTE parent-child to display the tree.... therefore updating these are done independently.

Comment: You should change `LIKE 'Y'` for `= 'Y'`

Comment: @Christian4145 yeah i know but i can't figure out how can do it

Comment: @maSTAShuFu exactly with cte i can view all the tree and managment table1 with out problems but the porpuse of the second table is not to lost old id's and id parents (requeriments of my work). i need them for update around 45 more tables (with no foreing keys or cascade (i dont designthat))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) or a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) statement and reassign the old value if the condition is not `true`.

```
update u
set u.id = IIF(s.active like 'Y', s.new_id, u.id),
    u.parent_id = IIF(s.active like 'Y', s.new_father_id, u.parent_id),
    u.active = s.active
from table1 u
inner join table2 s on u.new_id = s.old_id
```

Comment: this work, thanks i try to do that but with my 0 expertise i failed

Comment: @Carlos - glad to help and thank you for the clear question and your attempts to solve it.